# javascript record voice stop and save it on the 20 second

Tags: javascript, html

I took and modified code which record our voice and after click of stop button make it like .wav file. I made the code to start record onload and set function which click automatically after 20sec the stop button. But these function doesn't work! This code is right after `function startRecording() {
    console.log("recordButton clicked");`. The code which doesn't work is `setTimeout("function() {document.getElementById('stopRecording').click();}", 5000);`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Simple Recorder.js demo with record, stop and pause</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 </head>
 <body onload='startRecording()'>
  <div id="controls">
   <button id="recordButton" >Record</button>
   <button id="pauseButton" disabled>Pause</button>
   <button id="stopButton" disabled>Stop</button>
  </div>
  <h3>Recordings</h3>
  <ol id="recordingsList"></ol>
  <!-- inserting these scripts at the end to be able to use all the elements in the DOM -->
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/08e7abd9/dist/recorder.js"></script>
  <script>
    URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

var gumStream; //stream from getUserMedia()
var rec; //Recorder.js object
var input; //MediaStreamAudioSourceNode we'll be recording

// shim for AudioContext when it's not avb. 
var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var audioContext = new AudioContext; //new audio context to help us record

var recordButton = document.getElementById("recordButton");
var stopButton = document.getElementById("stopButton");
var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pauseButton"); 

//add events to those 3 buttons
recordButton.addEventListener("click", startRecording);
stopButton.addEventListener("click", stopRecording);
pauseButton.addEventListener("click", pauseRecording);

function startRecording() {
    console.log("recordButton clicked");
    setTimeout("function() {document.getElementById('stopRecording').click();}", 5000);
    /*
    Simple constraints object, for more advanced audio features see
    <div class="video-container"><blockquote class="wp-embedded-content" data-secret="vNsz0nPBL4"><a href="https://addpipe.com/blog/audio-constraints-getusermedia/">Supported Audio Constraints in getUserMedia()</a></blockquote><iframe class="wp-embedded-content" sandbox="allow-scripts" security="restricted" style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);" src="https://addpipe.com/blog/audio-constraints-getusermedia/embed/#?secret=vNsz0nPBL4" data-secret="vNsz0nPBL4" width="600" height="338" title="“Supported Audio Constraints in getUserMedia()” — Pipe Blog" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>
    */

    var constraints = { audio: true, video:false }

    /*
    Disable the record button until we get a success or fail from getUserMedia()
    */

    recordButton.disabled = true;
    stopButton.disabled = false;
    pauseButton.disabled = false

    /*
    We're using the standard promise based getUserMedia()
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia
    */

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
        console.log("getUserMedia() success, stream created, initializing Recorder.js ...");

        /* assign to gumStream for later use */
        gumStream = stream;

        /* use the stream */
        input = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

        /* 
        Create the Recorder object and configure to record mono sound (1 channel)
        Recording 2 channels  will double the file size
        */
        rec = new Recorder(input,{numChannels:1})

        //start the recording process
        rec.record()

        console.log("Recording started");

    }).catch(function(err) {
        //enable the record button if getUserMedia() fails
        recordButton.disabled = false;
        stopButton.disabled = true;
        pauseButton.disabled = true
    });
}
function pauseRecording(){
    console.log("pauseButton clicked rec.recording=",rec.recording );
    if (rec.recording){
        //pause
        rec.stop();
        pauseButton.innerHTML="Resume";
    }else{
        //resume
        rec.record()
        pauseButton.innerHTML="Pause";
    }
}
 function stopRecording() {
    console.log("stopButton clicked");

    //disable the stop button, enable the record too allow for new recordings
    stopButton.disabled = true;
    recordButton.disabled = false;
    pauseButton.disabled = true;

    //reset button just in case the recording is stopped while paused
    pauseButton.innerHTML="Pause";

    //tell the recorder to stop the recording
    rec.stop();

    //stop microphone access
    gumStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();

    //create the wav blob and pass it on to createDownloadLink
    rec.exportWAV(createDownloadLink);
}
function createDownloadLink(blob) {

    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var au = document.createElement('audio');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var link = document.createElement('a');

    //add controls to the <audio> element
    au.controls = true;
    au.src = url;
    //link the a element to the blob
    link.href = url;
    link.download = new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';
    link.innerHTML = link.download;

    //add the new audio and a elements to the li element
    li.appendChild(au);
    li.appendChild(link);

    //add the li element to the ordered list
    recordingsList.appendChild(li);
}
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do `setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById('stopRecording').click();}, 5000);`

Comment: @evgenifotia I made it but I saw that there is some mistake in console. It is written that Can not read propery 'click' of null at line 40.

Comment: Of course it will give you that mistake. there is no element with that id. change it to `stopButton` and add `onclick="stopRecording()"` to the button with the id `stopButton`

Comment: @evgenifotia Thank you! I didn't see that mistake!

Comment: @evgenifotia How can I rename filename to something other? I tried two option first I changed directly the two functions than I make some variable. Here is the line link.download = new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';

Comment: I don't understand aren't you already naming it like you want? if you mean that you want to change the name after naming it then just do the same thing `link.download =  'new_name.wav';
    link.innerHTML = link.download;`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to record audio with a vanilla JavaScript.

For example

```
<button id="audioRecordButton">RECORD</button>
function recordAudioFromMicrophone()
{
    var mediaRecorder;
    var audioRecordButton = document.getElementById( "audioRecordButton" );
    var time;
    var isStartRec = true;
        
    var run = function(stream)
    {   
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", getAudio);
            
        audioRecordButton.addEventListener("click", recordHandler);
    }
    function recordHandler()
    {
        if(isStartRec)
        {
            startRec();
            time = setTimeout(stopRec, 20000);
        }
        else
        {
            stopRec();
            clearTimeout(time);
        }
    }
    function startRec()
    {
        mediaRecorder.start();
        isStartRec = false;
    }
    function stopRec()
    {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        isStartRec = true;
    }
    function getAudio(blob){...}
        
    const enableAudio = { audio: true };
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(enableAudio).then(run);
}
```